# iPhone in Lost Mode Can I use same apple id on new phone

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, find-my-iphone, sim

My iPhone was recently lost, I put it in lost mode via icloud and I know it was found by someone because I got the email from icloud saying it's been found as well as a last known location...but it has since not come online anymore.

I have a new iPhone now which I want to setup like the old one but I'm still hoping the person who has the old iPhone returns it after realizing it's a paperweight to them without my apple ID(i had text saying reward available if returned).

My questions are:

-What would happen if I setup my new iPhone with the same Apple ID as the old one? Would that remove the old one in lost mode?

-What if I name the new iPhone with the same name as the old iPhone?

-I want my old phone number...what happens if I deactivate the old Sim in the lost iPhone, and have my carrier create a new sim for me so I can use in my new iphone? Would that mess up the lost mode?

---

I basically want to setup my new iphone like my old one but I don't want my old iphone to be taken out of lost mode

Comment: Locked iCloud boards (locked iPhone) are usually taken apart and sold for internal components, which can be bought inside China's malls or other resellers/phone repairers. So you can give up on people returning your iPhone alas. The same happened to my sister, there's no problem using the same Apple ID, but DO NOT reactivate the stolen iPhone. For the SIM, you can deactivate it, the phone will still be locked but it will stop trying to ping its location until a new SIM is inserted into. I do not know about using the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your new phone using a previous backup! You’ll need to use your same Apple ID and password, however I highly recommended you change your password once you set up the new phone, just Incase they do get into your old phone they would be able to mess a lot of things up!